# Solaris, capturing total TCP data in/out using netstat

Tags: solaris

On Solaris 10 say I wanted to capture the total bytes TCP bytes received and sent.

Using netstat -s, it seems like the sum of these 2 values gives the total TCP bytes in:

```
tcpInInorderBytes   =821116956
tcpInUnorderBytes   =803451
```

While this value gives me the total TCP bytes out:

```
tcpOutDataBytes     =481714121
```

Would that be a correct assumption, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, input bytes is the sum of  `tcpInInorderBytes` + `tcpInUnorderBytes` and the output bytes is  `tcpOutDataBytes`